# Is my transitivity proof correct for the relation over $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ where $(a,b)R(c,d) \iff (a \le c \lor b \le d)$?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm having a hard time developing abstract thinking to solve problems regarding a relation's properties. I've spend quite an absurd amount of time on this one, but I think I finally grasped a bit of the general idea. However, my solution feels a bit fishy, or informal. Can you take a look at it? Is it correct? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

> For $A = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, is defined the relation $R$
>   over $A$ where $(a,b)R(c,d) \iff (a \le c \lor b \le d)$. Determine whether the relation $R$ is transitive.

It seems quite likely that it is transitive.

We need to prove that $(a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(e,f) \implies (a,b)R(e,f)$

First, $(a,b)R(c,d)$ means that either $a \le c$ or $b \le d$.

Next, $(c,d)R(e,f)$ means that either $c \le e$ or $d \le f$.

Using the premise, we can conclude that these four cases occur:

- $a \le c \land c \le e$
- $a \le c \land d \le f$
- $b \le d \land c \le e$
- $b \le d \land d \le f$

All four are true, according to the premise. Let's pick up the first one:

$$a \le c \land c \le e$$

Is equivalent to

$$a \le e$$

Which is enough to prove that $(a,b)R(e,f)$.

---

As you can see, I just generated some combinations using the premise and one of them happened to be useful. This doesn't sound quite pretty. How can I improve this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using the premise, we can conclude that these four cases occur:
>
> - $a \le c \land c \le e$
> - $a \le c \land d \le f$
> - $b \le d \land c \le e$
> - $b \le d \land d \le f$
>
> All four are true, according to the premise.

No, **at least one** is true. If the first or the fourth is true, you’re in business, but what if only the second is true? Is that possible?

Yes, it is. For example, $\langle 1,2\rangle\mathbin{R}\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle\mathbin{R}\langle 0,1\rangle$, but ... ?

For this relation you may find it helpful to think graphically. Each pair $\langle a,b\rangle\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ corresponds to a point in the plane. $\langle a,b\rangle\mathbin{R}\langle c,d\rangle$ if and only if either

- $a\le c$, in which case the point $\langle a,b\rangle$ is **not to the right of** the point $\langle c,d\rangle$, or
- $b\le d$, in which case the point $\langle a,b\rangle$ is **not above** the point $\langle c,d\rangle$.

In my counterexample $\langle 1,2\rangle$ is not to the right of $\langle 1,1\rangle$, which is not above $\langle 0,1\rangle$, but $\langle 1,2\rangle$ is both to the right of and above $\langle 0,1\rangle$.

Comment: Daaaaamn. Back to scratch. I really like the graph idea, I wonder if I could use that more often for the other relations I tried.

Comment: @Omega: It’s worth a try whenever you’re looking at relations on ordered pairs of real numbers.

Comment: If a relation used single elements, would a metric line be a good analogy...?

Comment: @Omega: If the elements are real numbers, yes, though it may turn out to be even more useful to graph the relation itself as a subset of the plane. Of course it’s often the case that a relation doesn’t have a nice picture of that kind.

Answer (score 2):

$(2,2)R(3,0)$ and $(3,0)R(1,1)$ but $(2,2)R(1,1)$ is not true. If you change $\vee$ with $\land$, then it would be transitive.