# Finding the first, last, minimal and maximal elements in these relations.

Tags: relations, order-theory

I'm now learning about relations of order. This is what I gather:

- First element: Precedes all elements
- Minimal elements: Have no predecessors. The first element is always a minimal.
- Last element: Succeeds all elements
- Maximal elements: Have no successors. The last element is always a maximal.

I have three exercises. I did two of them. I didn't quite get the last one. Can you help check if my answers are right, and advice me regarding the last one?

---

> Over $\mathbb{N}$, $aRb \iff a \le b$

- The first element would be $1$ (or $0$), because it $\le$ all elements in $\mathbb{N}$.
- The minimal element is $1$ (or $0$), because it has no predecessors.
- The last element is… well, I guess there is no last element given that $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.
- The same goes for maximal element, I think.

---

> Over $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, $(m,n)R(r,s) \iff m \le r \land n \le s$

We can visualize this [as a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/554225/5775), right? The relation occurs only if the point $(m,n)$ is neither to the right or above of the point $(r,s)$.

- The first element should be the point to the very bottom-left of the graph. But since ZxZ expands infinitely in that direction, I guess there is no such element?
- The minimal element would have the same problem...
- The last and maximal elements... well, the same thing...

Hm. This is fishy. Did I do something wrong?

---

> Over $E \not = \emptyset$, $ARB \iff A \subseteq B$

And here I am not entirely sure about what to do.

Comment: Yah, those look right. Can you think of what a minimal element of the class of all non-empty sets might look like?

Comment: @dfeuer: Without actually knowing their contents? I'm afraid not....... Unless.... Maybe, wouldn't it be $\emptyset$ in this case? Since $\emptyset \subseteq whateverSet$?

Comment: You're thinking in the right direction, but the empty set is not in the class of non-empty sets, so it cannot be a minimal member thereof. You're almost there, though.

Comment: @dfeuer: Just to be clear, what is your definition of *"a set's class"*?

Comment: Omega, a "class", in theories that have them, is a collection of sets that may or may not be a set. In most theories, there is no *set* of all nonempty sets, but in NBG theory, Morse-Kelley set theory, etc., there is a *class* of all non-empty sets, and one could talk about finding a minimal element of that class.